# Xamarin Device.StartTimer doesn't work properly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

The way Xamarin.Form.Device.Timer works is not consistent across devices and platforms. Was trying to implement a timer where user must enter within 60 second time limit.

Tried two approaches :
Approach 1 : When I used the Device.Timer to wait for user for 60 seconds for user to enter input, the  timer stopped running  when the app went to background(on iOS devices). When app resumed it started running from the point where it went to background.(code not include, it is just a simple Device.Timer implementation)

Approach 2 : To achieve the above, I used the life cycle events to store the time when app goes to background and on Resume I did some calculation and made it run continuously.  (Included the code below)
However, this approach is also not working in some devices(either time passed is not consistent with one in UI or in some devices the timer stops when app goes to background, not able to debug as I don't have these devices with which it is not working). Is there any other way to achieve this for both android and iOS platforms?

```
    Constructor(){
        // Timer text binded to UI
        TimerText = "1.00 min";
        StartTimer(60);
    }

    bool stopTimer { get; set; }

    private string timerText;
    public string TimerText
    {
        get => timerText;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref timerText, value);
        }
    }


    public void SetTimerText(int secondsCount)
    {
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsCount);
        // Timer Text is binded to a label in UI
        TimerText = time.ToString(@"m\:ss");
    }

    private void StartTimer(int countSeconds)
    {

        SetTimerText(countSeconds);
        IsResendEnable = false;
        _countSeconds = countSeconds;
        stopTimer = true;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {   
            // Start from 60,..59,.. till 1 and then stop untill Send again is clicked

            _countSeconds--;

            SetTimerText(_countSeconds);

            string[] tokens = TimerText.Split(':');

            if (_countSeconds == 0)
            {
                StopTimer();
                stopTimer = false;
            }
            return stopTimer;
        });

    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        stopTimer = false;
        IsResendEnable = true;
        TimerText = "0.00";
    }

    public int TimeLapse = 0;
    public void OnResume()
    {
        TimeSpan TimeDifference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DeviceTimeBeforeSleep);
        int restartCounter = 60 - (TimeLapse + int.Parse(TimeDifference.Seconds.ToString()));
        if (restartCounter > 0)
        {
            StartTimer(restartCounter);
        }
        else
        {
            StopTimer();
        }
    }

    public void OnSleep()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        DeviceTimeBeforeSleep = DateTime.Now;
        TimeLapse = 60 - _countSeconds;
        _countSeconds = 0;
        stopTimer = false;
    }
    
    private async Task ResendCodeCommandExecute(){
        this.StartTimer(60);
    }
```

Comment: first, use `System.Timers`.  Second, your description of the actual problem is very vague.  Can you provide a specific example of the problem behavior?

Comment: @PoorneshV On Android, you can run a timer on a Foregrounded Service to keep an timer running while the app is in the background. There is no *direct* analog on iOS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios If all you are doing to trying to see if the user does "something" within the app in 60 secs, run a timer while in the foreground, store/retrieve the OS provide date/time on the app's lifecycle events.